# Show that $Y_n=n(1-F(X_{(n)})) $ converges in distribution to an exponential random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics

related to the topic that I was working on yesterday, I encountered a tougher one.

The assumption is that $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ are iid with cdf $F(x)$.  If
$Y_n=n(1-F(X_{(n)}))$ then I am to prove that $Y_n$ converges in distribution to an exponential random variable with the unit mean.

Here is what I have so far.

$$\begin{align} Pr[n(1-F(X_{(n)})) \le y]&=Pr[1-\frac{y}{n} \le F(X_{(n)})]\\
&= 1-Pr[F(X_{(n)})\lt 1-\frac{y}{n}]\\
&= 1-Pr[\left(F(X) \right)^n<1-\frac{y}{n}]\\
&= 1-Pr\left[F(X)<\left(1-\frac{y}{n}\right)^{1/n}\right]
\end{align}
$$
Here is where I stopped.

I am not confident that what I am doing is right...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that $F(X_{(n)})\neq (F(X))^n$. 
$$F(X_{(n)}) = F(\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)) = \max(F(X_1),\ldots,F(X_n)).$$
You can also use the fact that $F(X)\sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: Was my notation mistaken?  I thought that the cdf of $X_{(n)}$ was $[F(x)]^n$.  And one more thing, why is it okay to assume that $F(X)$ standard uniform?

Comment: Is $X_{(1)}, \cdots, X_{(n)}$ the order statistics, so that $X_{(n)} = \max\{X_1, \cdots, X_n\}$? It would be nice to explicitly mention this in your question.

Comment: @hyg17 Let me address your mistake now that the previous mess (my own comments) have been cleaned up. The $F(X_{(n)})$ inside $Pr(\ldots)$ is a random variable so you cannot directly exponentiate it (like NCh commented). Basically you were mixing up a CDF and a random variable.

Comment: Okay, so if I let F(X)=T for example, how can I proceed from $$1-Pr[T<1-y/n]$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left[ n(1 - F(X_{(n)}) \leq y \right]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left[ F(X_{(n)}) < 1 - \frac{y}{n} \right].
\end{align*}

Now, without assuming extra condition on the distribution function $F$ of $X_i$'s, we cannot provide a decisive answer.

> **Example.** Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with the parameter $p \in (0, 1)$, then
>
> $$ F(X_{(n)}) = \begin{cases}
> 1, & X_i = 1 \text{ for some } i \in \{1, \cdots, n\} \\
> 1-p, & X_i = 0 \text{ for all } i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}
> \end{cases} $$
>
> and thus $n(1 - F(X_{(n)})) \to 0$ almost surely, hence in distribution.

From now on, we assume that $U_i := F(X_i)$ has the uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$. (This is true for any continuous distribution.) Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left[ n(1 - F(X_{(n)}) \leq y \right]
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left[ U_{(n)} < 1 - \frac{y}{n} \right] \\
&= 1 - \left( 1 - \frac{y}{n}\right)^n \\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1 - e^{-y}.
\end{align*}

Therefore the claim follows.

Comment: I don't understand why $F(X_i)$ has the uniform distribution over [0,1].

Comment: @hyg17, As I mentioned, I *assumed* that $F(X_i)$ has the uniform distribution. This is not true for arbitrary distribution (such as discrete distribution), but this is true for arbitrary continuous distribution.

Comment: Okay, I understand that you it does not work when it is Bernoulli(p).  My question is, why does F(X) have the uniform distribution and why is this true for any continuous distribution?   I can see that since F(X) can only take values between 0 and 1...

Comment: @hyg17  If $X$ is continuous then consider the distribution of $F(X)$.... $P(F(X) \leq x ) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(x)) =F(F^{-1}(x)) = x$ where $0 \leq x \leq 1$... So $F(X)$ is uniform. The psedeo inverse $F^{-1}(x)$ needs continuity assumption.

Comment: So let me get this straight.  For any random variable, X, let its cdf be F(x).   We know that $F(x)=Pr(X\le x)$.  If we consider the values of F(x) we can treat it as a random variable whose output is [0,1].  Now, since $Pr[F(x)\le x]=x$, the distribution of F(x) must be standard uniform since it matches the cdf of a uniform distribution.  Am I correct?   What confuses me most is how F(X) and F(x) means something different...

Comment: @hyg17 Your explanation is correct. Note that $F(X)$ is a random variable, whereas $F(x)$ is a fixed value of $X$, requiring a particular value of the random variable $X$.

Comment: Thank you so much!